# Adding objects to a vector overwrites the existing ones

Tags: c++

I have two classes: **GenomeRankedNode** and **RandomRankedTPNGenerator**. **RandomRankedTPNGenerator** responsibility is just to randomly create a **GenomeRankedNode**. **GenomeRankedNode** has four attributes: int, int, int* and int. My main has a **vector** that should be populated using **RandomRankedTPNGenerator**. For this purpose, in main, I have:

```
std::vector<GenomeRankedNode*> population;
population.resize(50);
for (int i = 0; i < popsize; i++ ) {
    RandomRankedTPNGenerator* generator = new RandomRankedTPNGenerator();
    GenomeRankedNode node* = generator->randomNode(numParents);
    population[i] = node;
    delete generator;
}
```

In **RandomRankedTPNGenerator**, the important function is randomNode():

```
GenomeRankedNode* RandomRankedTPNGenerator::randomNode(int numParents){
    int function = randomFunction(); //just gets a random number
    int* weights = randomWeights(numParents); //just gets a random number
    int variance = randomVariance(); //just gets a random number
    GenomeRankedNode* node = new GenomeRankedNode(function, numParents, weights, variance); 
    return node;
}
```

The above code is generating random **GenomeRankedNode** properly. The problem is that, in **population**, as I add the objects, the existing ones are apparently "overwritten" (I know they are not actually being overwritten...). On the other hand, **population** is being populated with different addresses. If I am using a different instance of **RandomRankedTPNGenerator** to create a **GenomeRankedNode**, **GenomeRankedNode** objects are being created in different addresses, why are all the pointers in **population** pointing to the same space in memory causing the values pointed by population[i], for every i, to be the same?

Here is the code for the **GenomeRankedNode.cpp**:

```
int function;
int* weights;
int numNodeParents;
int variance;

double vars[11] = {0.0005, 0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 5, 10, 50};

GenomeRankedNode::GenomeRankedNode()
{
    function = 0;
    weights = 0;
    numNodeParents = 1;
    variance = 0;
}

GenomeRankedNode::GenomeRankedNode(int inFunction, int inNumParents, int* inWeights, int inVariance)
{
    function = inFunction;
    numNodeParents = inNumParents;
    weights = inWeights;
    variance = inVariance;
}

GenomeRankedNode::GenomeRankedNode(GenomeRankedNode* inNode)
{
    function = inNode->getFunction();
    numNodeParents = inNode->getNumParents();
    weights = inNode->getWeights();
    variance = inNode->getVariance();
}

GenomeRankedNode::GenomeRankedNode(const GenomeRankedNode &inNode)
{
    function = inNode.getFunction();
    numNodeParents = inNode.getNumParents();
    variance = inNode.getVariance();

    //deep copy
    if (inNode.getWeights()){
        weights = new int[numNodeParents];
        for (int i = 0; i < numNodeParents; i++)
            weights[i] = inNode.getWeights()[i];
    }
}

GenomeRankedNode& GenomeRankedNode::operator= (const GenomeRankedNode &inNode)
{

    //self-assignment check
    if (this == &inNode)
        return *this;

    function = inNode.getFunction();
    numNodeParents = inNode.getNumParents();
    variance = inNode.getVariance();

    // explicitly deallocate values
    delete[] weights;

    // deep copy
    if (inNode.getWeights()){
        weights = new int[numNodeParents];
        for (int i = 0; i < numNodeParents; i++)
            weights[i] = inNode.getWeights()[i];
    }
    else
        weights = 0;

    return *this;
}

GenomeRankedNode::~GenomeRankedNode(void)
{
    delete &function;
    delete &numNodeParents;
    delete weights;
    delete &variance;
}

int GenomeRankedNode::getFunction() const
{
    return function;
}

int* GenomeRankedNode::getWeights() const
{
    return weights;
}

int GenomeRankedNode::getNumParents() const
{
    return numNodeParents;
}

int GenomeRankedNode::getVariance() const
{
    return variance;
}

void GenomeRankedNode::setWeights(int *inWeights)
{
    weights = inWeights;
}

void GenomeRankedNode::setFunction(int inFunction)
{
    function = inFunction;
}

void GenomeRankedNode::setVariance(int inVariance)
{
    variance = inVariance;
}

double GenomeRankedNode::getRealVariance(int inVariance) const
{
    return vars[inVariance];
}
```

To check the misbehaviour, I added to main:

```
for (int i = 0; i < population.size(); i++){
  cout << population.at(i)->toString();
```

}

Given that population.size() = 3, the output is:

```
Function: 1
Weights: 1 1
Variance: 2

Function: 1
Weights: 1 1
Variance: 2

Function: 1
Weights: 1 1
Variance: 2
```

On the other hand, if I add the line:

```
cout << population.at(i)->toString();
```

in the loop that I use to generate the random GenomeRankedNode objects, I have:

```
Function: 0
Weights: 3 4
Variance: 1

Function: 1
Weights: 4 1
Variance: 3

Function = 1
Weights = 1 1
Variance = 2
```

Given this, my conclusion: for some reason, all created GenomeRankedNode points to the same slot in memory. So, whenever a new GenomeRankedNode is instantiated, all the other pointers (GenomeRankedNode*) will have their pointed values updated! It is similar to the shallow vs deep copy problem, but I don't know where it is being originated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please note that you are apt to rile people when you ask a question which is clearly about C++ but tag it with [tag:c] as well as [tag:c++] — avoid dual-tagging unless the question is explicitly about the difference between C and C++.

Comment: My guess is that you are always generating the same node as you start with the same random generator ever iteration.  Move the random generator up and out of the for loop and try again.

Comment: You probably don't want to create a `RandomRankedTPNGenerator` on each iteration, unless there's something about the design of the class that forces that behaviour.  You need to know how that works and guarantees different behaviour every time the class is constructed.

Comment: `randomNode` returns a `GenomeRankedNode*` but you use it to initialize a `GenomeRankedNode`?

Comment: Did NathanOliver's and Jonathan Leffler's comments help? Those seem to be likely candidates for the problem.

Comment: @NathanOliver, different nodes are generated. I checked by printing the node in randomNode() (confirmed that different addresses are allocated for node) and by printing the actual values of node.

Comment: @ryouma Yes it is generating new nodes each time but it they should all have the same value as you are always using the same random sequence.  Does it change if you change your code to this: http://pastebin.com/MKYqa990?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, that is how I used to have it. I tried the way you said, the way I posted and having randomNode() as a static function. All results in the same behavior.

Comment: @NathanOliver, the nodes are being generated fine. It doesn't change with your modifications. I will edit the question to present more details.

Comment: @aschepler, randomNode returns a GenomeRankedNode* indeed, but I didn't use it to initialize GenomeRankedNode. I used it to add elements to the vector<GenomeRankedNode*> population.

Answer (score 2):

One problem I see is you are setting the ith value of population to a `GenomeRankedType` instead of a `GenomeRankedType*` (the type you say population is storing).

So modify the top portion of code to:

```
std::vector<GenomeRankedNode*> population;
population.resize(50);
for (int i = 0; i < popsize; i++ ) {
    RandomRankedTPNGenerator* generator = new RandomRankedTPNGenerator();
    GenomeRankedNode* node = generator->randomNode(numParents);
    population[i] = node;
    delete generator;
}
```

Let me know if this helps you!

Comment: You are correct. Sorry about that. It was a typo. The behavior persists with your modifications.

Comment: Cool! I will check out the rest of your code and see if I can find anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I moved:

```
int function;
int* weights;
int numNodeParents;
int variance;
```

From GenomeRankedNode.cpp to GenomeRankedNode.h as **private**. This fixed the problem.